# Where should I put my htaccess files from my 301 redirect?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

We are switching from Cart32 (powered by ASP.Net) to OpenCart (powered by php). We have links all over the site pointing to the older cart location. We also have an older cart on our site consisting of a bunch of html pages that I used a META redirect on, but want to switch to a 301 redirect for these pages as well.

I want to redirect these pages:

- /cgi-bin/cart32.exe/TLDM-store
- /products/OrderForm/Default.htm

to

- /store/

I got this code for the first one:

```
# Permanent URL redirect - generated by www.rapidtables.com
Redirect 301 /cgi-bin/cart32.exe/TLDM-store http://www.tldm.org/store/
```

And this for the second one:

```
# Permanent URL redirect - generated by www.rapidtables.com
Redirect 301 /products/OrderForm/Default.htm http://www.tldm.org/store/
```

Where should I put these htaccess files? In the root directory or in the /cgi-bin/ and /products/ folders respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html#what) :

> A [htaccess] file, containing one or more configuration directives, is placed in a particular document directory, and the directives apply to that directory, and all subdirectories thereof.

Both solutions will work (in the root directory vs in sub directories), the difference is a matter of taste. If you have only two rules I would put them in the same file at the root folder, if you have more rules I would probably split them.

A third (better) solution, if you have access to the server configuration, [is to put the rewrite rules there](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html#when) :

> In general, you should only use .htaccess files when you don't have access to the main server configuration file. [...]  Likewise, mod_rewrite directives work better, in many respects, in the main server configuration.

Don't forget to enable and check the debug logs for the rewrite module say ([RewriteLog and RewriteLogLevel](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) for apache 2.2,
[LogLevel](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging) for apache 2.4) if you have troubles with rules that don't apply.